# Add time interval to a given time string

Tags: java

I need a function that adds interval to a given time string.

Example:

string time = "18:00:00" if i add 2 houres i will get "20:00:00".

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) and a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
SimpleDateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(time.parse("18:00:00"));
c.add(Calendar.HOUR,2);
System.out.println("New time: "+time.format(c.getTime()));
```

Output will be:

```
New time: 20:00:00
```